# Clarification is needed on bitwise not (~) operator

Tags: c, binary, logic, bitwise-operators

Suppose you have the following C code.

```
 unsigned char a = 1;

 printf("%d\n", ~a); // prints -2
 printf("%d\n", a); // prints 1
```

I am surprised to see -2 printed as a result of ~1 conversion:

The opposite of 0000 0001 is 1111 1110. That is anything but -2.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Write the value of 0 and -1 in binary.

Comment: "1111 1110 --> anything but -2" Where are you getting this?  That's exactly -2 in two's complement.

Comment: `~` is a _bitwise operator_, meaning it operates on the individual bits of a number; a _binary operator_ is an operator that takes two operands.

Comment: Use `%u` for unsigned decimal conversion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is two's complement.

In two's complement representation, if a number x's most significant bit is 1, then the actual value would be −(~x + 1).

For instance,

```
0b11110000 = -(~0b1111 + 1) = -(15 + 1) = -16.
```

This is a natural representation of negative numbers, because

```
0000001 =  1
0000000 =  0
1111111 = -1  (wrap around)
1111110 = -2
1111101 = -3 etc.
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement for detail.

---

BTW, to print an unsigned value, use the `%hhu` or `%hhx` format. See http://www.ideone.com/YafE3.

Answer (score 4):

[%d](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) stands for signed decimal number, not unsigned.  So your bit pattern, even though it is stored in an unsigned variable, is interpreted as a signed number.

See this [Wikipedia entry on signed number representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) for an understanding of the bit values.  In particular see [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: But in a call to a varargs function an `unsigned char` is more usually promoted to an `int` than an `unsigned int` so `%d` is likely to be the correct format specification in this case.

Comment: But `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` before the bitwise negation takes place. You'd have to cast back to `unsigned char` afterwards for it to work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

One (mildly humorous) way to think of signed maths is to recognize that the most significant bit really represents an infinite number of bits above it.  So in a 16-bit signed number, the most significant bit is 32768+65536+131072+262144+...etc. which is 32768*(1+2+4+8+...)  Using the standard formula for a power series, (1+ X + X^2 + X^3 +...) = 1/(1-X), one discovers that (1+2+4+8+...) is -1, so the sum of all those bits is -32768.